# lock scrolling on one direction while scrolling the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a web app that handles a huge amount of data. One of the functionalities is to draw a table with hundred of rows and tens of columns. Actually this is achieved using Excel and my client want to have in HTML a user experience similar to using excel.

The table overflow the container div both horizzontally and vertically and the user can scroll both directions. What I'd like to obtain is to handle the event of scrolling in one direction and, during this interaction, to prevent the other direction scroll.

Is there an handler in jquery for scrolling? Any idea on how to get this goal? I haven't find anything that suits my need googling around.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: why would you want to limit scrolling like that? If I scroll to the right to view a whole row, I can't scroll back to the left to view the next row? Are you embedding an Excel document?

Comment: No. What I want to get is like when I use arrows to navigate through the table: right arrow I only go right. Down arrow only down but with mouse action. 
It happens to me not to be able to follow one row or one column through the table: the effect is sort of a 45 degrees November!